# How to get data price use BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python

How to use Beautifullsoup to get pricing in 2 nested span tags:

```html
 <span itemprop="priceRange">
        <span>14.000đ - <span>160.000</span>đ</span></span>
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ just read the documentation of bs4

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
html = '''<span itemprop="priceRange">
   <span>14.000đ - <span>160.000</span>đ</span></span>'''
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find("span",{'itemprop':'priceRange'}).text

print(span)
```

Output:

```
14.000đ - 160.000đ
```